# How to have a website splash screen (web app)

Tags: android, web-applications

I am using Android phones and I have made a website designed as a web app.

ie. you add the web app to the homescreen, Android treats it as a web app by loading it full screen, etc.

I am using cache manifest so it also loads when the user is offline.

But I find there is a bit of a delay when loading the web app, maybe 2 or 3 seconds, where the screen is just white.

Is it possible, on Android, to add a splash screen here so the user knows the web app is loading?

Comment: What is "web app" ? Is it WebView ? You want to display something else while the WebView is loading your page ?

Comment: A web app is an HTML5 website designed to "look" like a native app. See https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/installtohomescreen

Comment: Then this question has nothing to do with Android. The tag android only refers to native SDK.

Comment: It has everything to do with Android. You can do it on iOS using `<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" href="img/splash.png" />` - but obviously that won't work on Android. I'm hoping there is an Android equivalent.

Comment: What you just wrote including the Chrome dev link show that this is NOT an Android question. You are not using Android SDK nor building an Android app. You are building an app meant to run in browser. You need to address this question to people familiar with web development NOT Android development.

Comment: Of course it's an Android question. I'm trying to do something that can be done on iOS, now I am trying to find out if I can do it on Android? It's not a generic web development question - I want this working on **Android** devices.

Answer (score 1):

As of Chrome M47, a splashscreen is automatically applied to all web apps when launched from the Home screen. The splashscreen is somewhat configurable via an app manifest file, but the standard is still under development. Splashscreens are a feature specific to Chrome for Android and are not available when using the legacy Android browser.

You can read more about the available splashscreen settings here:
https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/10/splashscreen
http://www.w3.org/TR/appmanifest/

Comment: Downvote because this does not answer the question. The question is how to add a splash page to a web page, not disable the Chrome splash screen.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I'm surprised by this downvote because I did answer the question. I merely supplemented the answer to include info that the Chrome splashscreen feature cannot be disabled (but have now removed it). Also, the question asked relates to web apps, not web pages, something that has a specific meaning on Android, and which was taken into account.

Comment: I see your point. I misread your answer and have removed the downvote.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the manifest.json to your stack and have it linked within the head like any standard link or meta tag.

Create the manifest.json:

```
{  
"short_name": "Voice Memos",  
"name": "Voice Memos",  
"start_url": "./?utm_source=web_app_manifest",  
"icons": [  
{  
  "src": "/images/icon-192x192.png",  
  "sizes": "192x192",  
  "type": "image/png"  
},  
{  
  "src": "/images/icon-256x256.png",  
  "sizes": "256x256",  
  "type": "image/png"  
},  
{  
  "src": "/images/icon-384x384.png",  
  "sizes": "384x384",  
  "type": "image/png"  
},  
{  
  "src": "/images/icon-512x512.png",  
  "sizes": "512x512",  
  "type": "image/png"  
}
],  
"background_color": "#FAFAFA",
"theme_color": "#512DA8", 
"display": "standalone",  
"orientation": "portrait"  
}
```

Add a link to the file:
   `<link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">`

And you'll also need to enable it:

```
`    <!-- Add to homescreen for Chrome on Android -->
<meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
<meta name="application-name" content="Your app name">
<link rel="icon" sizes="192x192" href="apple-touch-icon-192x192.png">`
```

There's more info in the link in the other answer as well:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/34376716/1876722