# Progressive Web App with animated launch screen

Tags: animated-gif, progressive-web-apps

How Can I set an animated launch screen like the one below, into my Progressive Web App? Is it possible?

[Animated Launch Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xX7HP.gif)

Comment: AFAIK, this is not yet supported. The closest that you could implement would be using Splash screen. As of [Chrome M47](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/10/splashscreen), "the splash screen is generated dynamically from information held in the Web App Manifest and is a combination of the name and background_color properties, and the icon in the icons array that is closest to "128dp" for the device."

Comment: Also stated in this [related SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34376716/5995040, [splash screen](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/lighthouse/audits/custom-splash-screen is configurable. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 11):

Currently PWA splash screen can only consist of a color, a logo, and an title. There are some [standards discussions happening](https://github.com/w3c/manifest/issues/589#issuecomment-323232119) around providing a more powerful API but nothing has been solidified as of this answer.

An option is to use the standard static splash screen and then animate into the content of your app. Here is a little sample code that creates an overlay matching your PWA's `background_color`, and then animates the background up into the toolbar. Obviously you'll want to tweak the coloring. You could even switch to a fade-in instead of a slide-up animation.

```
<style>
  #splash {
    background-color: #2196F3;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    z-index: 10;
    transition-property: top;
    transition-duration: 300ms;
    transition-delay: 300ms;
    transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 1, 1);
  }

  #splash.animate {
    top: -100vh;
  }
</style>

<script>
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    document.querySelector('#splash').addEventListener('transitionend', (event) => {
      event.target.remove();
    });
    requestAnimationFrame(() => {
      document.querySelector('#splash').classList.add('animate');
    });
  });
</script>

<div id="splash"></div>
```

[Sample](https://ultra-dresser.glitch.me/) - [Demo](https://photos.app.goo.gl/62Da5bTUeZglXbuG2) - [Source](https://glitch.com/edit/#!/ultra-dresser)

Comment: This is perfect for what I want. How can I make it so that the splash screen and animation transitions are only done when the user is accessing via the PWA and not also when through a browser?

Comment: @Mike I guess you could add a parm on the `start_url` and if that param is present do something else. You could probably also use a media query to only apply this to mobile screens.